# Python script to download files from JIRA using API Token

Tags: python, api, jira

I am new to Python and I am trying to create a script which logs into my JIRA system using the API key, downloads the issue list and and save it under my local drive. I am using the below script . But when I run the script I am getting the below error

url="https://auditservice.dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/audit/downloadlog?
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

See the script I used below

```
import requests

jira_token = 'xxxxxxxx'

url = 'https://yyy.atlassian.net/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-csv-all-fields/temp/SearchRequest.csv?jqlQuery=project+%3D+%22MASTER%22+ORDER+BY+created+DESC&atl_token=2d4dafe6-9c30-4e22-add9-7b3a2cea877b_8c7b7f55de7b75e76ea3f997ed4b30959c1eaf05_lin&tempMax=1000'

r = requests.get(url, auth=('jiraadmin@yyy.com', jira_token))

open('MyJiraIssues.csv', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Comment: The script you shared has an atlassian.net url, but the error message as an azure.com url.  Are you sure you got that exact error from this exact script?  In any case, "EOL while scanning string literal" means you are missing a closing quote.  For example, the line `url="https://auditservice.dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/audit/downloadlog?` does not have a closing quote at the end of the string.

Comment: May be you are sharing part of the script but try this

url="https://auditservice.dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/audit/downloadlog?"

Its missing the quotation marks at the end.

Comment: Calling API directly like this seems like a nightmare to maintain (URL format looks very fragile). Perphaps you could use something like this client library: https://jira.readthedocs.io/index.html IMO if that does what you need it should be more pleasant to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using JIRA Cloud.
If you are using on-premise Jira, you will need to obtain the security token from Atlassian.
There is no such thing as a temporary auth token in Jira, so the [Atlassian documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/app-security-tokens/) states that it only works for a limited time and needs to be renewed periodically. For example, if I have an auth token ending at 2020-05-30T13:42:22.123+0000, I need to use it until this date (or later). If it expires earlier than that, I need to get a new one.

If your auth token expires, you can always get a new one by logging in to your Jira account and following the steps in [How do I generate an authentication token?](https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/api-tokens-938839638.html).
But this creates a new auth token each time so it is not recommended if you are using on-premise Jira. If you are using Cloud, then this is the only option.
When you get the new auth token, it can be used just like the one you got in the first place. If your auth token expired, you can use the new one right away.

JIRA has a [help page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/api-tokens-938839638.html) which talks about this in more detail.

If you get the error that says "EOL while scanning string literal", then you are trying to decode a byte string and not a unicode string. You need to change your code from this:

```
open('MyJiraIssues.csv', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

to this:

```
open('MyJiraIssues.csv', 'w').write(r.content)
```